# ASP.NET Get UserControl Custom Event On Parent Page VB

Tags: asp.net, events, user-controls

I created a custom event to fire when a button is clicked on my usercontrol. I want to capture this event on my parent aspx page. I've tried numerous methods from searching the web, but none seem to work. Any suggestions?

```
'my usercontrol code behind
 Public Event DButtonClick As EventHandler
Protected Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    RaiseEvent DButtonClick(sender, e)
    Response.Write("1112333022")
    DeleteUser(ListBox1.SelectedItem.Value)

End Sub

'aspx code behind
   Protected Sub AdminEdit1_DButtonClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AdminEdit1.DButtonClick
    Response.Write("page")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to register the event handler in the code-behind of the parent page instead of through the markup

```
Public Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)  
    AddHandler AdminEdit1.DButtonClick, AddressOf AdminEdit1_DButtonClick
End Sub
```

I use C# and I am not sure if the above VB syntax correct, to verify, here is C# equivalent

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AdminEdit1.DButtonClick += new EventHandler(AdminEdit1_DButtonClick);
}
```

Sometimes it does not work from setting it from the markup as I had experienced in the past and I can not tell you why.